# How to open deep link in React Native app?

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

How to open link like viber://chat... & tg://... in React Native with standard Linking.

```
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { Linking.openURL(`viber://chat?number=0123456789`); }}>
            <View style={styles.messengerBlock} >
              <Image source={{ uri: 'viber' }} style={styles.messengerIcon} resizeMode={'contain'} />
              <Text style={styles.messengerText}>Viber</Text>
            </View>
```

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Viber you can only open these links: https://developers.viber.com/docs/tools/deep-links/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open another app in your app, you can use [react-native-app-link](https://github.com/FiberJW/react-native-app-link).

If you want your app be opened with deep linking, such as:

```
myApp://case/1
```

then take a look at [this article](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html).